# powertop doesn't give estimate

Tags: linux, monitoring, process

Running powertop 2.8 doesn't give power estimate.

- It is a battery powered device (not a laptop though).
- Have run powertop enough number of times. (how many times is enough
  though?)
- Host OS: centos 8, Guest OS: Debian 10. Getting estimate on HostOS,
  not GuestOS. On guest OS, /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop is missing and less /var/cache/powertop/saved_results.powertop doesn't give anything.
- Hypothesis: Tried reading up documentation, thought maybe acpi
  interface isn't available to the guest OS, so passthrough via qemu,
  no clear documentation available for this though. Gave up as
  /proc/acpi/ path was available for guest OS. Any pointers for this?

Comment: What device is it?

Comment: It's a portable battery powered server

Comment: Does it reveal the required information via ACPI, or is the battery essentially a bolted on UPS that the system is unaware of?

Comment: Required information is revealed via ACPI

Comment: @vidarlo It's actually an In-flight-entertainment server. On running powertop, saw cpufreq_stats failedLoaded.

Comment: Also, Idle stats are missing as well. cpufreq driver not being passed through to the VM?